# Passed variable from code behind to javascript not updating

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to pass the newly selected row index of the gridview to my javascript in aspx page. But the code only fetch the initial value of the variable and when the script runs again, it contains the not updated value.

variable in my code behind is "SelectedRowIndex" which is an integer

```js
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        console.log('<%= SelectedRowIndex %>');
        var validArrowKey = false;
        var index = '<%= SelectedRowIndex %>';

        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            validArrowKey = true;
            index++;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 38 && index > -1) {
            validArrowKey = true;
            index--;
        }

        if (validArrowKey) {
            var trPaymentDetails = document.getElementById("trPaymentDetails_" + index.toString())

            if (trPaymentDetails) {
                __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdPaymentDetails', 'Select$' + index.toString());
            }
            else
                __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdPaymentDetails', 'Select$' + index.toString());

        }
    }, false);
```

To set the initial value for the selected row index, the user must click a row in the gridview first, inside that inclick trigger will set the variable to the user's selected row.

Comment: You just assigned an anonymous function that will be executed each time when keydown event was fired. So the variable declaration inside will be executed each time as well. That's why it will always be initial value. Try to declare index as a global variable.

Comment: The user first must click a row in the gridview to set the first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `index` variable global by moving it outside the function, then it will only be set once.

```
var index = '<%= SelectedRowIndex %>';
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        console.log('<%= SelectedRowIndex %>');
        var validArrowKey = false;

        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            validArrowKey = true;
            index++;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 38 && index > -1) {
            validArrowKey = true;
            index--;
        }

        if (validArrowKey) {
            var trPaymentDetails = document.getElementById("trPaymentDetails_" + index.toString())

            if (trPaymentDetails) {
                __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdPaymentDetails', 'Select$' + index.toString());
            }
            else
                __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdPaymentDetails', 'Select$' + index.toString());

        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: ok it works but why is that when I get the new total rows in the Gridview still returns 0 even if it has rows in it? I put it above the function as well


            " var totalRows = '<%= grdPaymentDetails.Rows.Count %>'; "

Comment: That's tricky to answer without having all of the code, both server side and client side. You could instead replace '<%= grdPaymentDetails.Rows.Count %>' with the Count property of the grids "datasource"